# Most clean and pythonic way to concatenate numbers and strings in a loop while maintaining a prefix of zeros

Tags: python

Say I want to download files from websites and files are listed by this style

```
www.website.com/file001.mp3
www.website.com/file002.mp3
www.website.com/file003.mp3
.
.
.
www.website.com/file451.mp3
www.website.com/file452.mp3
www.website.com/file453.mp3
```

And I want to make some code that'll download these using a loop.

```
for i in range(1, 454):
    downloadFunction('www.website.com/file00'+i+'.mp3')
```

This would not work when i is bigger than 9 because then the concatenation would look like

```
'www.website.com/file0010.mp3'
```

instead of

```
'www.website.com/file010.mp3'
```

I could code the case for each hundreth's value but I have a feeling there is a more elegant way to code this.

Comment: Hint: You can use the `.format` method to build your file names. Also, your existing code only works if `i` is a string, it will fail if it's an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the a [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) string, you could do:

```
url_template = 'www.website.com/file{:03}.mp3'

for i in range(9, 12):
    print(url_template.format(i))
```

Output:

```
www.website.com/file009.mp3
www.website.com/file010.mp3
www.website.com/file011.mp3
```

So, for your application:

```
url_template = 'www.website.com/file{:03}.mp3'
for i in range(1, 454):
    downloadFunction(url_template.format(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
for i in range(1, 454):
    downloadFunction('www.website.com/file'+str(i).rjust(3,'0')+'.mp3')
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.zfill), which is a string function that pads a string with leading zeroes. In your case:

```
for i in range(1, 454):
    downloadFunction('www.website.com/file{}.mp3'.format(str(i).zfill(3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `downloadFunction('www.website.com/file%03d.mp3' % i)`. The `%` is a placeholder and the `d` is a numeric format-specifier. The `03` tells Python to zero-pad up to three characters.